# How to get multiple values in row wise in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, ms-office, export-to-excel

Below is my Workbook Sheet1

[image]

Am expecting sheet2 like below,
Total Item column (Using countifs I can get but Sub_Item1,2 and 3 How do I use Match Index in Excel)

[image]

Comment: Are you on Excel-2010 or later version?

Comment: I am using Ms office 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use countifs to count total_item `=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$12,D3)`. For sub items use below formula. Then drag down and right as needed. If need to handle errors then use `IFERROR()` function.

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$3:$A$12)-ROW($A$2))/($A$3:$A$12=$D3),COLUMN(A$1)))
```

[image]